# e-mail verification via url with $_GET variables working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, email

I am verifying user accounts when the following succeeds:

```
if (!empty($_GET['email']) AND !empty($_GET['hash'])) {
    // sanitize $_GET data
    $_GET = DB::instance(DB_NAME)->sanitize($_GET);

    // declare variables for ease of use for $_GET data
    $email = ($_GET['email']);
    $hash = ($_GET['hash']);

    // make sure the data we $_GET is the data we are expecting (matches in the database)
    $match = DB::instance(DB_NAME)->select_rows("SELECT email, verify_hash, verified FROM users WHERE email='" . $email . "' AND verify_hash='" . $hash . "' AND verified='0'");
    $match = count($match);

    // if there is a match, activate the account
    if ($match > 0) {
        // change 'verified' column from 0 to 1
        $q = array('verified' => 1);
        $verify_user = DB::instance(DB_NAME)->update('users', $q, "WHERE email='" . $email . "' AND verify_hash='" . $hash . "' AND verified='0'");

        // send success message
        $this->template->content->message = "Your account has been activated, you can now login";

        // get user type from users table
        $q1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
        $result = DB::instance(DB_NAME)->select_row($q1, 'array');

        // if we have a teacher, update the teachers table
        if ($result['type'] == 'teacher') {
            // prepare default pic and username
            $data = Array(
                'user_id'   => $result['user_id'],
                'avatar'    => 'blank_teacher.png',

                // need a username to access profile view -- if not random enough, specify ON DUPLICATE KEY condition
                'user_name' => $result['first_name'] . rand()
            );
            $update_teacher = DB::instance(DB_NAME)->insert('users_teachers', $data);

            // prevent page errors from SQL query failing when new teachers don't have at least one subject that they teach
            $data = Array(
                // '32' stands for 'other' subject
                'subject_id'    => '32',
                'users_user_id' => $result['user_id']
            );

            $update_at_least_one_subject = DB::instance(DB_NAME)->insert('teachers_subjects', $data);
        }
    } else {
        // No match: invalid url or account has already been activated.
        $this->template->content->message = "The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.";
    }
} else {
    // Invalid approach
    $this->template->content->message = "Invalid approach, please use the link that has been sent to your email.";
}
```

Strangely (at least to me), this works perfectly on my localhost, but miserably on my live server. I basically can't get the url received via email to work, which looks like the below:

```
myurl.com/users/email_signup_verification?email=john.doe@yahoo.com&hash=ccb1d45fb76f7c5a0bf619f979c6cf36
```

I keep getting my own error message: "Invalid approach" which (logically) would seem to be issued when either one of two $_GET variables, 'email' or 'hash' are empty. It seems to me that they are definitely not empty.

Anyway, I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot differences between local and live. Everything else seemed to work okay. Originally I was checking to make sure that the 'email' and 'hash' were also 'set', as in isset('email'), so i removed that feature, but that didn't resolve the issue.

UPDATE:

my htaccess file contents:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: Why include email in the URL if you're including a unique id? All you need is `email_signup_verification?hash=ccb1....`.

Comment: @meagar I removed email from the verification url, still no dice... works on the local, but not on the server

Comment: That was a simple observation, not a suggestion for solving your problem.

Comment: Are you url encoding your variables? That `@` can throw you sometimes

Comment: @Machavity just url encoded my hash variable in the email (email has been since removed from url), still same issue. works on local, but not on the server

Comment: Does `sanitize()` take an array or a string? Are you missing the subscript?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your RewriteRule on the server make you miss the query string?
You can check the .htaccess file.

Comment: just added .htaccess file contents to question -- any idea how that could affect the query string?

Comment: `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,QSA,L]`, add [QSA] modifier to your rewrite rule
means Query String Append